# Minus operation in java 8 for subtracting Lists

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, java-stream

Suppose I have two lists:

```
List<Integer> list1 =  Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
List<Integer> list2 =  Arrays.asList(1, 2, 4, 5);
```

Now I want to perform `(list1 - list2)`. The expected ouptut is `{3}`. How to do this using java 8 streams?

Comment: please consider the set operation (-)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you must use Streams:

```java
List<Integer> diff = list1.stream()
  .filter(item -> !list2.contains(item))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
List<Integer> difference = new ArrayList<>(list1);
difference.removeAll(list2);
System.out.println("Remove: " + difference); //3
```

Comment: Implementation is correct but this is not intersection. This is subtraction. Intersection should result into common elements between two Sets.

Comment: @mdev - Done. Just renamed the variable. This answer does answer question by OP.

Answer (score 4):

Using Apache commons:

```
CollectionUtils.subtract(list1, list2);
```

Pros: Very readable. 
Cons: No type safety